# Mongodb connection failed

Tags: mongodb

I have created a mongodb cluster and trying to connect via mongo shell, but getting below error. Is there something wrong that I am doing?

```
mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase <DATABASE> --ssl --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD>

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:22.341+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017
2017-06-02T18:59:22.342+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
2017-06-02T18:59:27.220+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:28.685+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:30.120+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:31.553+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:32.679+0530 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:34.072+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:35.546+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:36.981+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0
2017-06-02T18:59:36.981+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: connect failed to replica set cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-qvc6m.mongodb.net:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:223:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well the reason is in the error `No primary detected for set cluster0-shard-0`. So the replica set is likely in a state of election. You need to look at that and see what is causing **that** particular issue.

Comment: BTW. The new question about why the replica set does not have a primary is "off-topic" for StackOverflow, since it would be about configuring the database. [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) is where you can ask.

Comment: @Neil Lunn: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be because of difference in the mongo shell version on the host(3.2.12) vs the mongo engine version used. You can try making the versions same for both then it should work.

Answer (score -1):

if you have this error `exception: connect failed`
Type this command in terminator linux:

```
sudo -s

sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: Thanks Michel, but I am using cloud.mongodb cluster

Comment: like this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237663/mongo-atlas-connection-authentication-failed-with-custom-databases?answertab=active#tab-top)